# Простой фреймворк с готовой системой регистрации и доступом к БД

Tags: framework, php, база-данных

Нужен очень простенький php фреймворк с готовой системой регистрации и доступом к БД. 
Подскажите.

Comment: Если вас kohana не устраевает - пишите свой.

Answer (score 2):

Kohana. Модуль Auth есть в коробке, можешь сделать регистрацию любой сложности.

Для доступа к БД есть как своя ORM, так и доктрина.

Из всех популярных фреймворков считается самая быстрая. Сам использую ее давно, клиенты не жалуются.

Answer (score 0):

Есть минифреймворк – [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org).

В нем используются из основных компонентов:

- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) для общения с БД (DBAL)
- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) для шаблонов

Весь список есть на сайте. Готовой регистрации нет (для это вам только CMS), но есть компоненты для быстрой реализации.

Answer (score -1):

Kohana? Может вам вообще CMS нужен?

Comment: не, он большой. Мне нужно минимум кода.

Comment: поройтесь на github

Comment: старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы